# When I use `golang.org/x/time` NewLimiter(), limit higher burst, Allow() will return true higher burst

Tags: go, time

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
go version
```

Output:

> go version go1.12.17 darwin/amd64

#### What version of package are you using (`rate version`)?

```
golang.org/x/time v0.0.0-20190308202827-9d24e82272b4
```

#### What did you do?

Run the following on amd64:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    t := time.After(time.Second)

    limit := rate.Limit(100)
    burst := 10
    l := rate.NewLimiter(limit, burst)

    var count int
    for {
        select {
        case <-t:
            fmt.Printf("%ds, %d\n", time.Now().Sub(now).Nanoseconds()/1e9, count)
            return
        default:
            if l.Allow() {
                count++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

```
1s, 10
```

#### What did you see instead?

```
1s, 110
```

I am confused about `count` is not equal to the burst size. When I set Limit=100, burst=10, it should Allow() for maximum calls is burst.

Comment: From the [docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.Burst): *Burst is the maximum number of tokens that can be consumed in a single call to Allow, Reserve, or Wait*. You are calling the single token variant of `Allow`, so you are well below the burst.

Comment: Please read on [the theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket#Burst_size) first.

Comment: I don't think those questions (from the answer wizard?) should be included. Can you [do](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62674202/edit) the needful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burst is not the maximum rate. It's the number of tokens in the bucket *in addition to* the refill rate.

You set the rate to 100 tokens per second and the burst capacity to 10.

It is not surprising at all that you can consume 100 tokens in the one second your program runs, plus the 10 tokens added by the burst capacity.

If you want to allow no more than 10 things to happen in one second, set the rate to 10 and burst to zero.

Comment: I apologize for taking a year to retrieve my account and revisit my question. Thank you for your clear answer, which has helped me understand. Indeed, the correct answer should be 110, as tokens are also generated during the one-second consumption period, which relates to the burst size. Initially, I misunderstood the token bucket algorithm and overlooked the refill rate when calling the 'Allow()' method. Thanks again for your help.